# Using OpenLayers with alternative map source to integrate Google Street View?

Tags: openlayers, google-street-view

I am researching any possibilities of Using an alternative map source other than Google that I can integrate Google Street View.

Due to the drastic rate changes for Google Maps API I would like to use OpenLayers with Here Maps API and integrate only Street View from Google Maps API.

Is this possible?

Comment: It would be breaking the terms: 
3.2.4  (d) No Use With Non-Google Maps. Customer will not use the Google Maps Core Services in a Customer Application that contains a non-Google map. For example, Customer will not (i) display Places listings on a non-Google map, or (ii) display Street View imagery and non-Google maps in the same Customer Application.  https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/